# Pig Programming with UDF

Tags: apache-pig

I have a date as Chararray datatype in Pig.

I need to get the Month of that date in words.

The below is file that contains dates alone

```
06/28/2014
08/28/2014
09/17/2014
10/10/2014
```

It is loaded like this :

```
myinput = LOAD 'file' AS(mydate:chararray);
```

I need output as

```
Jun
Aug
Sep
Oct
```

Is there any built in functions available for this?
Do I need to create a UDF to extract the month alone?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the month by using a Substring

```
Substring(mydate,0,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by built-in function or streaming.

### built-in function

In pig 0.12, there are ToDate function to generate time object.

```
data = LOAD './code/pig/data/date.txt' AS (d:chararray); 
month = foreach data GENERATE ToString(ToDate(d, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MMM') AS month_abbr; 
DUMP month;
```

Output looks like:

```
(Jun)
(Aug)
(Sep)
(Oct)
```

### Streaming (bash)

Create a bash script named “get_month.sh”

If you are using Mac, the content should like this:

```
while read line
do
    echo "date -jf %m/%d/%Y ${line} +%b" | bash
done
```

Or change the echo line accordingly for different *nix system.

This bash script will take the date from standard input and convert it into month

to use it in the pig script, just use:

```
data = LOAD './code/pig/data/date.txt' AS (d:chararray);
month= STREAM data THROUGH `./get_month.sh` AS (month_abbr:chararray);
DUMP month;
```

Output looks like:

```
(Jun)
(Aug)
(Sep)
(Oct)
```

Pig is very flexible and that’s why I love Pig!